# Spring boot won't recognize an added dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

I am trying to add the `ModelMapper` dependency via `pom.xml`, however, when I try create a new instance of modelMapper it doesn't recognize the dependency and instead tries to import modelMapper from `Swagger`. I have tried adding it manually and still I get the same problem.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!--                 PARENT                -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>golden.scent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>something</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <!--                 PROPERTIES                -->

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!--                 DEPENDENCIES                 -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <!--                 BUILD                 -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Configuration**

```
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.ModelMapper;


@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper(){
        return new ModelMapper()


    }
}
```

Tried using the `invalidate cache/restart` which usually solves the problem. not this time.

I am trying to use DTO beans and do not want to write a mapper manually.

I have tried looking for solutions but could not find one yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your class to the following:

```java
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper(){
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

If with this you can't compile your code, you might need to delete `org/modelmapper` folder in the `.m2` folder in your machine and reload your maven dependencies again.

Answer (score 1):

Try nuking your .m2 folder, and then pull dependencies again. I usually do it like this: delete everything from .m/repo, I go to intellij and add space in pom.xml and delete it so it offers me to pull changes that were made in pom.xml

If that does not help, you can always run from your terminal

`mvn clean` - clear dependencies so you get something like a clean slate

`mvn install` - initiates the pulling of dependencies again